# Why can't I split a string with the dollar sign?

Tags: java

I want to split a string which has content like this:

```
a$b$c
```

but when I use:

```
String data=...
data.split("$");
```

it does not recognize $ and do not split string but when I replace $ by some Letter like X it works.
does anyone has any Idea?

Answer (score 107, accepted):

The split function takes a regular expression, not a string, to match.  Your regular expression uses a special character - in this case '$' - so you would need to change it to escape that character:

```
String line = ...
String[] lineData = line.split("\\$");
```

Also note that split returns an array of strings - Strings are immutable, so they cannot be modified.  Any modifications made to the String will be returned in a new String, and the original will not be changed.  Hence the `lineData = line.split("\\$");` above.

Comment: Technically, the regex argument to String.split() is an object of type String.  But the method expects it to be in a regular expression format.

Comment: Yes, that is correct - apologies if I did not make that clear, or if I was confusing in that statement.

Comment: Split returns String[], not String.

Comment: @ColinD - you are correct.  Self dope slap procedure has been initiated

Comment: Any reason as to WHY only $ is not recognized and why we need to add \\ to it?

Comment: Because **String.split(String param)** the "param" needs to be a regular expression.

Answer (score 15):

The split method accept a String as the first parameter that is then interpreted as a Regular Expression.

The dollar sign is a specific operator in regular expressions and so you have to escape it this way to get what you want:

```
String data = ...
String[] parts = data.split("\\$");
```

Or, if the delimiter may change you can be more general this way:

```
String data = ...
String[] parts = data.split(java.util.regex.Pattern.quote("$"));
```

Answer (score 3):

`split()` uses a regular expression as parameter. You have to call `split( "\\$" )`, because `$` is the regular expression for "end of line".

Answer (score 3):

String.split() in Java takes a String argument which is a regular expression.  The '$' character in a regex means the end of a line.  You can use an escape sequence ("\\$") if you are looking for a dollar sign in the string.

Sources:

[String](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html) - Java API

[Pattern](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) - Java API

Comment: Don't forget to escape the \ aswell.. so make that ("\\$")

Comment: @Tim - Yes, that's what I wrote... it just only showed up as a single backslash.  I'm still pretty new to SO and its editor.

Answer (score 3):

$ is a special character in regular expressions representing the end of the line. To match a dollar sign, use `"\\$"`.

Answer (score -1):

You may have an issue with the uniCode characters for non-breaking spaces. Try...

```
String[] elements = myString.split("[\\s\\xA0]+"); //include uniCode non-breaking
```