# how to separate a java string that is separated by "$"?

Tags: java, groovy, spock

I am using spock to test a java app.It seems "$" is a special character in groovy.any java string  that is separated by "$" can't be separated in groovy properly.Any workaround for this problem?

### update

The "split" happened in java code that I can't edit. It turns out that java code has a problem same as:[Why can't I split a string with the dollar sign?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2168831/string-split-function-in-java-does-not-work)

Comment: i am not a groovy expert, but I would try '\$'

Answer (score 1):

<s>I don't think `$` is a special character in Groovy strings.</s> *Edit: Yes, it is, if you use [GStrings](http://groovy.codehaus.org/Strings+and+GString)! But the rest may still be useful:* But it's a special character in the string you give to [`String#split`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split-java.lang.String-), because that string is interpreted as a regular expression, and in a regular expression, `$` is "end of input" (or end of line, depending on flags).

If you're using `String#split`, to make it split on a literal `$`, you have to escape it with a backslash. To make the regex engine see a backslash, you have to escape the backslash in a string literal with *another* backslash.

[Example](https://groovyconsole.appspot.com/script/5745060998021120):

```
'testing$one$two$three'.split('\\$').each {
  println it
}
```

Output:

```
testing
one
two
three
```

Better yet, as [suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25823866/how-to-separate-a-java-string-that-is-separated-by/25823892?noredirect=1#comment40399047_25823892) by [Dónal](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2648/d%c3%b3nal), use `tokenize`:

[Example](https://groovyconsole.appspot.com/script/5182111044599808):

```
'testing$one$two$three'.tokenize('$').each {
    println it
}
```

*(Same output)*

Comment: you can avoid escaping the `$` if you use the `tokenize` method instead of `split`

Comment: sorry,I didn't explain it carefully,and updated question just now.

Comment: @AlexLuya: If the `split` is correctly coded in Java code, it should work. My guess is you want to to be using `'` rather than `"` in the string you're passing to it.

Comment: thanks,you are right,java code has a problem same as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2168831/string-split-function-in-java-does-not-work.