# Java String Split Behavior - Split on Dollar Symbol

Tags: java, string, split

I am trying the following code (running java version 1.7 in Eclipse Luna IDE on Ubuntu Linux 12.04):

```
String str = "abc$xyz"; 
String[] split_ = str.split("$");
System.out.println(split_.length);
```

I am always getting a split of length 1. If I try to print `split_[0]`, I am always getting the entire string. Can anyone suggest what might be the cause?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2168831/string-split-function-in-java-does-not-work

Comment: ************* To the moderator: you are welcome to delete this question. Please no more downvotes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because `split` expects a regular expression. Since "$" is the end-of-line marker in a regular expression, this only splits on the end of the String.

You should use

```
String str = "abc$xyz"; 
String[] split_ = str.split("\\$");
System.out.println(split_.length);
```

instead.

This escapes the "$", so that it's treated as a literal character instead (and uses two slashes to escape the backslash as part of the string literal).

Comment: @Downvoter Did I make any mistake? I'd appreciate knowing what it is, so I can correct it.

Comment: This worked for me, thanks !

Comment: Someone downvoted my question as well :(

Comment: @Jake :( Glad you got your answer (from three people :P) at least.

Answer (score 0):

The `$` character is a metacharacter meaning "end of line", not a literal dollar sign.

Escape the `$` character with two backslashes, one to escape the `$` in the regular expression, one for a Java escape for a backslash.

```
String[] split_ = str.split("\\$");
```

Answer (score 0):

`.split()` uses regex that is why...

Try this:

```
String str = "abc$xyz"; 
String[] split_ = str.split("\\$");
System.out.println(split_.length);
```